# RethinkDB - how to filter records where attribute matches a list / array

Tags: arrays, filter, match, rethinkdb, reql

#### RethinkDB

I want to fetch all the records which have a particular field/attribute matching one of 3 different possible values.

*In the example below, I want to see all the records who have `status` equal to 'Ready', 'Active', or 'Something else'*

I would expect to be able to do something like this :

```
r.db('db').table('table').filter(

  function (rec) { 
    return [ 'Ready', 'Active', 'Something else' ].includes( rec('status') );   
  }

);
```

That doesn't error, nor does it return me all the records that have status equal to 'Ready', 'Active', or 'Something else' (it returns no results).

#### How do I find all records with a field matching any one of the values in an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution to this which is closer to your initial hunch is using [`.contains(...)`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#contains):

```
r.db('db').table('table').filter(
  function (rec) { 
    return r.expr(['Ready', 'Active', 'Something else']).contains( rec('status'));   
  }
);
```

This is likely more efficient than using regex.

Comment: Nice - thank you for that - I'm flagging yours as the correct answer for being a closer match to my original approach.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out after reading a bit more about the [**ReQL**](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/) query language.

We don't have a JS function in there, instead it is ReQL, which basically just means you can use `.match()` and a regular expression.
The regular expression to match a list is simply to seperate the matching strings with bars "|".

So the solution to the above example is

```
r.db('db').table('table').filter(

  function (rec) { 
    return rec('status').match( "Ready|Active|Something else" );   
  }

);
```